# Как выполнить очередь с нужными интервалами?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Есть список задач. Обозначен как задача и время выполнения. Время считаем относительным. То есть если указано, что первая задача должна быть запущена в 1.01.2016 13:50:10,456, а вторая в 1.01.2016 13:50:10,496, то первая задача будет запущена в текущее время, а вторая должна запуститься через 40 мс.

Я уже голову сломал как это осуществить.

Понятно, что каждая задача должна быть запущена в отдельном потоке.
Проблема в том, что на создание потока тоже нужно время, а интервалы между задачами могут быть и 1 мс. При этом я не могу позволить себе потерять даже 1 мс.

Была идея заранее запустить потоки, а в них крутить луп (или включить таймер) для старта задачи, но список задач может иметь десятки тысяч задач

Comment: Откуда у вас такие чудные требования, про 10000 задач и то что даже 1мс нельзя потерять? Учитывая, что поток никак не гарантирует время выполнения. Может быть вам вообще нужна ОС реального времени?

Comment: @Kromster, из ТЗ )))))

Comment: Я к тому, что может быть проблема решается совсем с другой стороны

Comment: @Kromster, это моделирование нагрузки на сервер БД. Поэтому потеряв 1 мс, я могу потерять пиковый момент.

Comment: Без системы реального времени этого сделать невозможно. Обычные ОС никогда Вам не дадут нужной точности, без погрешностей.

Comment: а если каждый поток будет считать сколько нужно времени до начала и потом засыпать на это время?

Comment: @ixSci, меня не ограничивают в ресурсах. RT у меня конечно нет, но нагружать процессор я могу как угодно. Погрешность допустима, но точность должна быть 1 мс.

Comment: Что-то типа DDoS устроить хотите на продакшн сервере? И еще вопрос, а как вы тогда собираетесь получать и синхронизировать время на машинах с точностью до 1мс ?

Comment: @MaximK, я думал об этом, но читайте в вопросе: `Была идея заранее запустить потоки, а в них крутить луп (или включить таймер) для старта задачи, но список задач может иметь десятки тысяч задач`. Короче столько потоков одновременно создать нельзя

Comment: @Kromster, это уже меня не касается. Думаю, такая погрешность уже учтена, поэтому мне и поставили такие жесткие рамки

Comment: А почему вы решили, что надо все 10000 задач в потоках держать? По идее есть менеджер, он может создавать потоки задачам например за 1-2 сек до старта. У вас же не будет больше десятка одновременных задач?

Comment: @Kromster, больше десятка не будет, но менеджеру для старта задачи тоже нужно время. Если я не буду пользоваться системным пулом потоков, а создавать потоки вручную, то поток будет создаваться за 50-100 мс...

Comment: Ну так отлично, стартуете поток для задачи за 1000мс с запасом, и потом в потоке уже по более точному таймеру запускаете тело.

Comment: @Kromster, очень похоже на костыль, но пока сойдет.

Comment: _Гарантию_ вызова в определённый момент может дать вам только RTOS. С обыкновенной системой никаких гарантий нет, ваш поток может быть отправлен в спячку хоть на полчаса. Те, кто писал ТЗ, не слишком-то хорошие специалисты.

Comment: @VladD, мне вспомнилось видео про 7 красных линий. Но что поделать, я же специалист, придется выполнять )))

Answer (score 4):

*Выношу резюме своих уточнений из комментариев*

Откуда у вас такие чудные требования, про 10000 задач и то что даже 1мс нельзя потерять? Учитывая, что поток никак не гарантирует время выполнения. Может быть вам вообще нужна ОС реального времени?

Все 10000 задач в потоках держать не надо. По идее есть менеджер, он может создавать потоки задачам например за 1-2 сек до старта. У вас же не будет больше десятка одновременных задач?

Ну так отлично, стартуете поток для задачи за 1000мс с запасом, и потом в потоке уже по более точному таймеру запускаете тело.

Answer (score 2):

На старт нового потока нужно менее миллисекунды, так что нет смысла так рано, за 1-2 секунды стартовать. Для синхронизации старта задачи можно использовать `ManualResetEventSlim`, у него минимальные издержки, т.е. поток запускается, и вызывает `Wait()`, поток менеджер в нужное время вызовет `Set()`. Для отсчёта времени подойдёт `Stopwatch`, а в качестве таймера можно в цикле `Thread.Sleep(0)` вызывать. Да, потоком не помешает максимальный приоритет выставить. Только сборщик мусора всё равно будет картину портить периодически.